# Error in eosjs account creation on localnet

Tags: nodeos, accounts, eosjs, permissions

I am trying to create an account using eosjs in node.js. I am using :

```
eos = Eos({keyProvider});
eos.transaction(tr => {
        tr.newaccount({
            creator: 'eosio',
            name: 'account1',
            owner: pubkey,
            active: pubkey
        })
```

With this `eos` instance, I am successfully calling the `getblock` api. WHile hitting this api, i get the error:

> {"code":500,"message":"Internal Service
>   Error","error":{"code":3090003,"name":"unsatisfied_authorization","what":"Provided
>   keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared
>   authorizations","details":[]}}

Error is same on `nodeos` console too. I tried some solutions available out there bu they didn't work for me. I am accessing local node running on same system. Please let me know the resolution of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign the transaction you can do it by

```
 eosConfig = {keyProvider: ['YOUR_CREATOR_PRIVATE_KEY']}
 let eos = Eos(eosConfig)
 eos.transaction(tr => {
        tr.newaccount({
            creator: 'eosio',
            name: 'account1',
            owner: pubkey,
            active: pubkey
        }) \.then( (resp) =>{
      console.log("EOS resp ", resp);});
```

As you are on localnet then you need only one parameter to pass in eosConfig which is keyProvider.

Comment: Yes i have done that. To ensure the correctness of eos instance, i have written in question that i am able to access getblock and similar apis. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: I also updated it in the question @Mr.Y

Comment: yes you will be able to call getblock because getblock action don't need authorization but if you want to do transaction then you need authorization and that will be done by only providing private key to key provider.

Comment: Yes, i have tried to add authorization in the instance creation and in transaction both, it is not working anyway. Have you tried account creatoin using eosjs successfully?

Comment: yes i have tried many times

Comment: in key provider, which private key we provide? Who is the transaction signer here, eosio?

Comment: yes you need to provide private key of eosio

Comment: No, `eosio` is not the caller. newaccount creates a new account in the name of the caller. You provide the key of the caller. This is the call that is done through web sites as well: https://www.myeoskit.com/#/tools/create

Comment: Same code as in question worked for me just by putting the private key of eosio.  Due to first answer of this question by riccardo: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/eosjs-what-is-the-keyprovider?rq=1  i underestimated the private key.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an authority to eosconfig, e.g.:

```
eos = Eos({
    keyProvider,
    authorization: EOSIO_ACCOUNT_NAME + '@active',
  });
```

Comment: no luck, same error. I have also tried putting options in transaction too like this: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs#options

Comment: then it is a problem with your account names, maybe you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: I have checked each and everything. Have you tried creation of account using eosjs? @friedger

Comment: @A.K. That works for me:
    let eos = Eos({
      keyProvider: DOCTORS_KEY, // private key
      httpEndpoint: HTTP_CHAIN_API_ENDPOINT,
      chainId: CHAIN_ID,
      authorization: DOCTORS_ACCOUNT_NAME + '@active',
    });

    
    eos.newaccount({
      creator: DOCTORS_ACCOUNT_NAME,
      name: THE_NEW_NAME,
      owner: DOCTORS_ACCOUNT_NAME,
      active: DOCTORS_ACCOUNT_NAME
      }).then(r => console.log("ok: " + r))
      .catch(e => console.log("err:" + e))

Comment: Are you sure that no transaction creation is needed and in this line `owner: DOCTORS_ACCOUNT_NAME, active: DOCTORS_ACCOUNT_NAME` , we will be putting the name not the key?

Comment: yes, it worked for me (TM) and yes, name not key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83570/discussion-between-friedger-and-a-k).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error shown when performing an action on a test network, and I solved it updating my permissions launching this single cmd:

```
cleos.sh set account permission <your-account> active '{"threshold":1,"keys":
[{"key":"<your-public-key>","weight":1}],"accounts":
[{"permission":{"actor":"<your-account>","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' 
owner -p <your-account>@owner
```

Hope this can help you, but actually needs an account to be done.

Comment: I hope for this command account should be already there. I am trying to create one. Please add more details.

Comment: Are you working with the mainnet or with the Jungle Testnet?

Comment: localnet , i mean a nodeos running locally on my machine

Comment: Never worked on the local, but here I find some stuff that can be interesting for you: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4289. Check answers from `daithi-coombes`

Comment: That thread is interesting although i have created account using cleos on terminal, now i am looking to do the same using code

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    eos = Eos({ keyProvider : "PR_KEY"});

eos.transaction({
              actions: [
                  {
                      name: "newaccount",
                      account:"cat",
                      authorization:[{
                          actor:'cat',
                          permission: 'active'
                      }],
                      data: {
                          creator:"cat",
                          name:"newaccount",
                          owner: "PUB_KEY",
                          active: "PUB_KEY"
                      }
                  },
              ]
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            });
```

Comment: please change cat with eosio

Comment: It was working too after putting the right private key.